# How to cancel a valid Schengen visa and apply for a new visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, business-travel, 90-180-visa-rules

I have a valid Schengen multiple-entry business visa valid for one year, from 6 September 2015 to 5 September 2016. I traveled to Germany from 6 September 2015 to 31 October 2015, for 54 days. I need to travel again from 10 January 2016 to 02 April 2016, for 84 days. With this visa I cannot travel as the duration of stay is more than 90 days within 180 days. Can I cancel this visa and apply for a new visa? What is the process for this?

Comment: Do check the calendar, I think there are only a few days missing, this trip might be possible on your current visa if you shave a week or two at either end or even in the middle (short trip back home, to the UK or elsewhere?).

Comment: I checked with the [calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html), it seems that if you enter on January 10, you only have 34 days of stay left. But if you enter on January 30 or any day after that, you have the full 90 days again. Leaving for 21 days at any point during your stay would also make you able to return and stay until April the 2nd.

Comment: Can I suggest not giving dates as number/number/year as they mean different things in different parts of the world. Writing the month name avoids confusion.

Comment: phoog posted as a comment below the best answer. " you will need to get a type D long-stay visa, or else change your travel plans." Actually, the question is pointless. You can't just tweak a visa into another type or reset it, you'll need a different one.

Comment: @Relaxed , Could you please help in how to use the calculator "http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html" as I could get the 90 days stay even if entering 30 Jan 2016. Many thanks .

Comment: @suvendubishoyi That seems correct, what if you enter January 29?

Comment: @Relaxed entering 29 january will be also fine , but need 90 days in one go ,

Comment: @suvendubishoyi OK, but what do you see when you try January 29 with the calendar?

Comment: @Relaxed , could you please tell me what date I should entry with Date of entry/Control .

Comment: @suvendubishoyi You enter the date on which you wish to enter and the calculator tells you how long you may stay, based on the previous stays you entered in the table down below.

Answer (score 15):

The 90 day period is a computed on a rolling basis and hence, as other posters have mentioned, you cannot circumvent this by applying for a new visa.

Schengen C visas are specifically for short stays and you are NOT allowed to work but only conduct business meetings, discussions, trainings etc. 
Since you are staying for long continuous periods, there may also be a question on your real intention vis-a-vis the intent of the C visa.

Comment: (+1) Excellent point! The duration of stay is not the most pressing problem in this case.

Answer (score 11):

Obtaining a new Schengen type C visa does not change anything to the [90-day-in-any-180-days limit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule) as it also applies across several visas. A new visa does not open any fresh rights to stay in the Schengen area above the 90-day threshold.

If your intended stay is longer than allowed under this rule, any visa application should be refused for this reason alone. So cancelling your current visa and applying for a new one is pointless.

The only solution is to secure another type of visa/permit from Germany. I don't know how realistic this would be in your situation but those are entirely separate from Schengen visas and cancelling your current visa is therefore in any case unnecessary.

Should you ever want to have a Schengen visa cancelled, you can ask the consulate that issued it (or perhaps another one) to revoke it, the Schengen visa code provides for that. But, again, it would not solve your problem in this case.

Comment: Kindly suggest can I apply for a new visa without canceling the existing visa .

Comment: @suvendubishoyi No, not a Schengen short-stay visa. A German long-stay visa, maybe, you would need to ask the German consulate about that but I would not hold my breath (that's what I allude to in the third paragraph). There is no easy fix, the regulations are specifically intended to prevent what you want to do. Look at it this way: Come April 2, you would have stayed almost 5 of the last 6 months in Germany, that's not a short visit anymore, you are practically becoming a resident.

Comment: Please suggest how to go for 3 months with Schengen business visa: category C.

Comment: @suvendubishoyi YOU CAN'T. It's forbidden, that's what the 90-day limit is about, you already used most of that, you have to stay out of the Schengen area for some time or use something else than a type C visa. For the rest, please refer to my answer, asking the same question over and over won't change the rules.

Comment: @suvendubishoyi you will need to get a type D long-stay visa, or else change your travel plans.

Answer (score 6):

- If you are working for a German company, you may qualify for a "blue card" work visa. This requires a job with a salary of 48400 Euro per year (or less in some fields).
- If you are self-employed, you can get a work visa if the business plan is credible and if positive effects for the German economy can be expected.